# YouTube Data API Comments: Insert mention @username in a reply

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

**Problem:**

```
There're COMMENT THREADS (parent comments) under a YouTube Video. 
There're COMMENT REPLIES (replies to parent comments) under a comment thread.
I want to post a COMMENT REPLY including (mentioning) the @author of the comment I'm replying to.
```

**Example:**

*Parent Comment Thread (posted by Adam White):* "**Love this video!**"

- |--*Child Comment Reply (posted by Eve Black):* "**Why everybody likes it?**"
- |--*MY COMMENT COMES HERE (posted by Anton Frolov):* "**@Eve Black because it's awesome!!**"

[image]

The guys here seemed to have a solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49185982/10584570
I didn't go far with it though.

```
textOriginal = "+[Eve Black] because it's awesome!!"
textOriginal = "+/channel/UCeMvTX0kLEDXEKrxMnCk-BA because it's awesome!!"
textOriginal = "+[UCeMvTX0kLEDXEKrxMnCk-BA] because it's awesome!!"
textOriginal = "@UCeMvTX0kLEDXEKrxMnCk-BA because it's awesome!!"
textOriginal = "+UCeMvTX0kLEDXEKrxMnCk-BA because it's awesome!!"
```

Just gets posted as a raw text. 
code piece:

```
response = youtube.comments().insert(
    part="snippet",
    body={"snippet": {
        "parentId": "UgzpEQFrEGFZbvj3gZp4AaABAg",
        "textOriginal": textOriginal}}).execute()
```

Docs:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/insert

A ton of karma to anybody trying to help

Comment: As far as I know, the YouTube Data API does not offer the feature you're looking for.

Comment: please edit your question and include your code and describe any issues you are having with your current solution.

Comment: DaImTo, I appreciate your time. The code might confuse readers, as the question is about the textOriginal parameter inner formatting/keywords to be accepted by google API not as raw text. Post updated

Comment: @AntonFrolov I really need a solution to this problem too. You'd think if YouTube went through the effort of implementing this api that they wouldn't just leave out a crucial feature. The api is now almost pointless, since a majority of comments are replies.